# Non-renormalization theorems at large N

Tags: particle-physics, supersymmetry, conformal-field-theory, superconformality, large-n

I know of numerous examples of non-renormaliation theorems in theories with SUSY - e.g. the non-renormaliation of the superpotential in 4d theories. However, I've never seen a non-renormaliation theorem proven for a large N expansion.

For instance, sometimes, if one computes the scaling dimension of BPS operators at large N for N=2 SCFTs in 3d, one gets the exact dimension of the operator to first order in N. Since the scaling dimension is set by the R-charge of this operator, such operators should not receive any other corrections in the large N expansion.

However, checking that the next order corrections vanish is not obvious. Is there any paper that discusses this and proves that all next order corrections in the large N expansion have to vanish (without using the fact that the dimension is set by the R-charge)?